# Particle density animation using dynamic texture

Tags: texturing, particles

I want to make the particle system to flow from dynamic texture using the density property.

Unfortunately for some reason particle system memorise only the first frame of the texture, and ignore future changes of the texture.

Any hints how making this work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known limitation of the particle system as noted in a bug report [here](https://developer.blender.org/T34063).

To quote Brecht Van Lommel, from that bug report:

> The location of emitted particles are determined in advance now and
>   stay fixed, so this can't be animated. There's been some working on
>   designing an improved particle system that can handle such animations
>   but it's not finished

It is currently listed as a 'To do' item on the development section of the blender wiki [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Todo/Tools#Particles).